# Move app data (on /data/data) to SD card

Tags: sd-card, storage, app-data

I bought one of those budget phones that claimed to have 4GB of internal storage, but it looks like there is only 1.08GB. I don't know why it says that I only have 1.08GB if I already used 1.12GB for apps.

[image]

I removed all bloatware and moved all my APKs to the SD card, but I still don't have enough space for Google Docs, etc.

The main culprits are SpanishDict and Facebook, which take up 200MB of internal storage each (at `/data/data/com.spanishdict.spanishdict` and `/data/data/com.facebook.katana`)

Of course, I googled before asking and such, and I used this program called FolderMount. But it doesn't seem to work well with moving things outside of the SD card, defeating the whole purpose of it.

Does anyone know a way to *actually* move app data from the internal storage to the SD card?

Btw, I am using a Lanix X200.

TL;DR no space on the internal store because of app data on `/data/data`. Need to move it to an SD card.

Answer (score 0):

First, when they say there is 4 GB storage, they count all partitions, so there is 4 GB on your phone.

To move data to an SD card, you will have to use an app called Link2SD (root required) or use an adoptable storage feature (Android 6+ only). In both cases, you don't move folders manually if you do that you will probably screw up something.

Also, if you really need a Facebook app, use the lite version, or access it via a browser. The normal version uses too much space and too many resources. Generally, I say this because I assume you don't have more than 768 MB of RAM, so use it wisely.

Check out the [Link2SD's tag wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/link2sd/info)

Answer (score 0):

There are many apps for this purpose. Some of them are APPtoSD and Link2SD. Another possible way is that when you insert a new SD card into your phone, it automatically asks, and you should select "format and use as internal storage".